# Is there a way for GDB to print type without omitting template parameters?

Tags: c++, gdb

It seems that for several STL containers, GDB omitts printing its template parameters. For example

```
(gdb) whatis a
type = std::vector<int>
```

And it causes problems for me.

```
(gdb) whatis std::vector<int>::_M_impl
No type "vector<int>" within class or namespace "std".
(gdb) p *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>(0x7fffffffd920)
A syntax error in expression, near `*>(0x7fffffffd920)'.
```

To get what I want, I have to manually add the not shown template parameters.

```
(gdb) whatis std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_impl
type = std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_impl
(gdb) p *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >*>(0x7fffffffd920)
$5 = ......
```

However, this isn't ideal since it is hard to generic program adding these omitted template parameters. For example, given `std::map<int, double>`, how can I know there are extra template parameters `Compare` and `Allocator`, thus able to get `std::less<Key>` and `std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T> >`

Is there a way for GDB to print type without omitting template parameters? Or is there another way around my problem?

Comment: @Jans How is that a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for GDB to print type without omitting template parameters?

Use TAB-completion. Example:

```
$ cat t.cc
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<char, int> m = {{'a', 1}, {'z', 2}};
  return 0;
}

$ g++ -g t.cc && gdb -q ./a.out
(gdb) start
Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0xa87: file t.cc, line 5.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at t.cc:5
5     std::map<char, int> m = {{'a', 1}, {'z', 2}};
(gdb) n
6     return 0;

(gdb) p 'std::map<TAB>   # Note: single quote is important here.
```

Completes to:

```
(gdb) p 'std::map<char, int, std::less<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<char const, int> > >
```

Now you can finish with:

```
(gdb) p ('std::map<char, int, std::less<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<char const, int> > >' *)&m
$1 = (std::map<char, int, std::less<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<char const, int> > > *) 0x7fffffffdb60
```

And finally:

```
(gdb) p *$1
$2 = std::map with 2 elements = {[97 'a'] = 1, [122 'z'] = 2}
```